# Is there a convenient ferry between Sardinia and Corsica?

Tags: ferries, mediterranean, sardinia, corsica

I have flights to Olbia, Sardinia for three nights first weekend of May (because they were cheap). I thought it might be nice to spend a night in Corsica (and bring my TCC count up to 41). Are there any convenient ferries? It looks as if there is a short ferry from Santa Teresa di Gallura to Bonifacio but has no rail link (I get car sick on buses and don't fancy an infrequent service that stops everywhere). There seems to be a ferry from Porto Torres to Propriano, with two trains a day. Any advances on that? (I don't speak any of the local lingos and I don't drive.)

Comment: Ferries are very infrequent, and trains poor. I'll have to be satisfied with staying in Sassari.

Answer (score 3):

There is a site that lets you book the [ferry from Porto Torres to Propiano](http://www.aferry.co.uk/porto-torres-propriano-ferry.htm).

There appears [to be one to Ajaccio](http://www.ferrysavers.co.uk/porto-torres.htm) as well

Both operated by [SNCM](http://www.ferrysavers.co.uk/sncmferries.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[Corsica/Sardinia ferries](http://www.corsica-ferries.co.uk/crossing/ferry.html) has connection between both islands islands

Comment: They run on the Santa Teresa di Gallura to Bonifacio route, but getting to Santa Teresa requires a long, slow and infrequent bus journey.